# Printing simple text using fetch and await. Why do I need more than one await inside an async function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to do webcrawling using fetch on React Native. This is what I'm doing:

```
  const response = fetch(
        url,
        {
            body          : post_data ? post_data : undefined, // must match 'Content-Type' header
            cache         : 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            headers       : headers,
            method        : post_data ? 'POST' : 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            redirect      : redirect ? 'follow' : 'manual', // *manual, follow, error. TODO: is manual the right keyword?
            referrer      : 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
        }
    );

    const http   = await response;
    const header = http.headers;
    const html   = http.text();

    console.log(html);
```

When I print `header`, I can see the headers. When I print `html`, this is what I see:

```
{ _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? I thought one await was necessary, but if I change to:

```
const http   = await response;
const header = await http.headers;
const html   = await http.text();

console.log(html);
```

then I can see the HTML. But as I've read, [await makes the execution pause and resolves the Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). So why should I need the two extra awaits below await response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a step back, `await` accepts a promise as its argument. Looking at the docs for `fetch`. [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) returns a promise. [`response.headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers) is not a promise. [`response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) returns a promise.

Given all of that, `await response.headers` is not necessary, but your other two are.

As for *why* `response.text()` returns a promise, the critical piece is that the `response` promise resolves as soon as the request starts getting data back, which is *before* the response data has already been received. This means that `await response` waits to know "did the server response, and if so with what status code/header`, and`await response.text()` waits for the actual data that the server sends.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the response is one promise, while reading it's content is a second promise. That's why you need to await twice.

Equivalent without async/await would be:

```
   fetch("/url")
    .then((response) => response.text() /* check response status and etc */)
    .then((response) => console.log(response) /* actual response text /*);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, which is a stream that *does not actually contain the response content*. You have to call one of the methods to read the stream and return the actual content.

For example:

```
const response = await fetch( /* your parameters */ );
const responseText = await response.text();
```